# Is there a way to add SqlTrackingService to WorkflowApplication in WF4?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've been searching for a way to add the SqlTrackingService to the WorkflowApplication in WF4 similar to the way it can be done in WF3 as follows:

```
WorkflowRuntime wr = new WorkflowRuntime();
SqlTrackingService ts = new SqlTrackingService("Initial Catalog=Tracking;Data 
Source=localhost;Integrated Security=SSPI;");
ts.UseDefaultProfile = true;
wr.AddService(ts);
wr.StartRuntime();
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WF4 has the concept of [TrackingParticipant](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee513993%28v=vs.100%29.aspx). You can *attach* tracking participants to your workflow execution and it will receive its events.

You can implement a SQLTrackingParticipant. Check these [WF examples](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21459) where you've available an example of an custom SQLTrackingParticipant on *\WF\Basic\Tracking\SqlTracking* folder.

Comment: I was hoping to use the default profile. Do they no longer have the default profile or the SqlTrackingService out of the box?

Comment: No, they don't. You've to implement it yourself. The link I gave you already implements one to.